# String manuplation and SQL search

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have image table which contain resolution column, I like to search by width or height of images.

My actual column value is e.g. 1920x1280.

I want to search something like 1920 > 2048 or 1280 > 1800
so I can list if image is hd, 4k, or 8k.

I guess I need to manipulate resolution column first though I have no idea how achieve it.

Comment: Can you be more clear with your explanation? If possible quote some snippet example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table design violates the rules of [First Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) and you're run into it's effect. The best way is to split this column by two, width and height, and make simple filter condition as you wish.

Comment: yes thats my backup plan.. just wanted to know if thr is any way i can make this work

Comment: Sure, there are several other ways to do this. Say, you can define a view which parses this column to width and height and filter this view. But that's a crutch while best decision is don't break the leg.